# total number of rows of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a very large query that is supposed to return only the top 10 results:

select top 10 ProductId from .....

The problem is that I also want the total number of results that match the criteria without that 'top 10', but in the same time it's considered unaceptable to return all rows (we are talking of roughly 100 thousand results.

Is there a way to get the total number of rows affected by the previous query, either in it or afterwords without running it again?

PS: please no temp tables of 100 000 rows :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dump the count in a variable and return that

```
declare @count int
select @count = count(*) from ..... --same where clause as your query

--now you add that to your query..of course it will be the same for every row..
select top 10 ProductId, @count as TotalCount from .....
```

Comment: this effectively runs the query twice - once to get the count and once to get the top 10 results out of it. Is there no way to avoid running it twice? The execution time for it is of several seconds

Comment: no there is not if you want the total rows, however 100000 rows is not a lot of rows, is the table very wide and more importantly is your where clause covered by indexes..also you don't need an ORDER BY in the count query

Comment: it's a wide table and it does lots of joins, and lots of filtering. I'm afraid it's as optimized as it can get. I was only hoping of not running it twice

Comment: CTE/analytical functions might be better then variable and 2 queries - don't know details of MS SQL planner, but it would stand to reason that planner might take advantage of dealing with the same table/indexes... see link that I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using an ORDER BY clause already (to properly define which the "TOP 10" results are), then you could add a call of ROW_NUMBER also, with the opposite sort order, and pick the highest value returned.

E.g., the following:

```
select top 10 *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by id desc) from sysobjects order by ID
```

Has a final column with values 2001, 2000, 1999, etc, descending. And the following:

```
select COUNT(*) from sysobjects
```

Confirms that there are 2001 rows in sysobjects.

Comment: Thats a nice solution, but you could also use COUNT instead of ROW_NUMBER so you don't have to order the table twice. 
select top 10 *,COUNT(*) OVER () from sysobjects order by ID

Comment: @Lamak - you could add that answer yourself, if you like. I always forget `COUNT(*) OVER()`

Comment: Yeah, I believe your answer is correct, and it should be accepted, thats why i didn't post mine, its basically the same.

Comment: @Lamak - surprisingly, in this simple case, the ROW_NUMBER version seems to perform slightly better than the COUNT one. I think it would be one where you'd try both ways and see which one performs better.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could hack it with a union select

```
select top 10 ... from ... where ...
union
select count(*) from ... where ...
```

For you to get away with this type of hack you will need to add fake columns to the count query so it returns the same amount of columns as the main query. For example:

```
select top 10 id, first_name from people
union
select count(*), '' as first_name from people
```

I don't recommend using this solution. Using two separate queries is how it should be done

Comment: I'm not sure this does not runs the query twice

Comment: The result set returned will change because you are adding an 11th row which is your count.

Comment: In essence yes it does run two queries, You can't do what you are trying to do in just one query, ultimately in your application you can run two queries or run a union select which is the same thing.

I'm unsure if union is available outside of oracle though. which only leaves you the option of running two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking **no** - reasoning is as follows:

*If*(!) the query planner can make use of TOP 10 to return only 10 rows then RDBMS will not even know the exact number of rows that satisfy the full criteria, it just gets the TOP 10.

Therefore, when you want to find out count of all rows satisfying the criteria you are not running it the second time, but the first time.

Having said that proper indexes might make both queries execute pretty fast.

**Edit**
MySQL has [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) which returns the number of rows that query would return if there was no LIMIT applied - googling for an equivalent in MS SQL points to analytical SQL and CTE variant, see [this forum](http://programming.itags.org/sql/17559/) (even though not sure that either would qualify as running it only once, but feel free to check - and let us know).